# The key of the dict in the python array is the most frequent

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have an array with some dictionaries in it.

Although the following method can be achieved.

But I have to do some more processing on the returned value, which I think is very bad.

Is there a better way?

```py
data = [{'name': 'A'},
        {'name': 'A'},
        None,
        None,
        {'name': 'B'},
        {'name': 'B'},
        {'name': 'B'}]
process = list(map(lambda x: x.get('name') if isinstance(x, dict) else None, data))
result = max(process, key=process.count)

for _ in data:
    if isinstance(_, dict) and _['name'] == result:
        array_index = _
        break

print(data.index(array_index))
```

`{'name':'B'}` appears the most times.

Where is the data array `{'name':'B'}`?

According to the above example, I want to get `4`.

But the code above has to be processed by the for loop again, which I think is very bad.

Comment: There's more elegant wats like use ```itertools``` or convert to Pandas series and use ```count_values()``` but both of them works like a normal loop. Actually I think there's no way you can do it without check all the list items.

Comment: using 2 separate `for` loops does not affect the time complexity of your solution. At the end `O(kn) = O(n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I used github copilot to see how it will solve this problem

```
def get_index_of_most_frequent_dict_value(data):
    """
    Return the index of the most frequent value in the data array
    """
    # Create a dictionary to store the frequency of each value
    frequency = {}
    for item in data:
        if item is None:
            continue
        if item['name'] in frequency:
            frequency[item['name']] += 1
        else:
            frequency[item['name']] = 1

    # Find the most frequent value
    most_frequent_value = None
    most_frequent_value_count = 0
    for key, value in frequency.items():
        if value > most_frequent_value_count:
            most_frequent_value = key
            most_frequent_value_count = value

    # Find the position of the most frequent value
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i] is None:
            continue
        if data[i]['name'] == most_frequent_value:
            return i
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comparisons of time:

```
My solution (a): 5.499999999998562e-06 seconds
Your solution (b): 7.400000000004625e-06 seconds
```

`a < b?` Yes

Comment: The most frequent in data is `{'name':'B'}`, what I need is the position of `{'name':'B'}` in the array.

Comment: I can also write a method to solve the problem like you, but what I want is whether I can get the answer I want without using the for loop .

Comment: But write one more method so that the code is still very long. I don't like it.

Comment: Copilot rewrote the code to find the position of `{'name': 'B']}` as well.  Sorry the function is too long, but it's faster and simpler to your solution. I'll see if you can do it without for-loops.

Comment: I don't think you can solve this without for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do

```
import ast
data = [{'name': 'A'},
        {'name': 'A'},
        None,
        None,
        {'name': 'B'},
        {'name': 'B'},
        {'name': 'B'}]
x={str(y):data.count(y) for y in data}
j=ast.literal_eval(max (x))
print(j)
```